# US visa point of contact

Tags: visa-refusals

I am visiting a friend in the US who is doing au pair work with a family there. I put her contact details on my DS-160 form as my US point of contact and my visa was denied. Could it be the problem? Should I rather put the contact details of the people she is working for on my form? What else can possibly be the reason for a 214b denial?

Comment: There must be some reason why they denied your visa.Pls. post the reason (E-Mail/letter you got).

Comment: @Pikkewyn Can you upload a copy of the refusal letter with your personal details redacted? There is a good overview of possible refusal reasons here http://visarefusal.com/214b/ ranging from simple failure to meet or comply with the requirements, through limited ties to home country, suspicious-looking invitation etc.

Comment: US Visa Refusal unlike UK Refusal letters are unhelpful and posting here will serve no purpose

Comment: Note to potential close-voters: this is not a question about long-term travel or immigration. The asker wants to get a short-term visa to make a short-term visit to the USA.

Comment: Always ask at the interview for the specific reasons why you are being denied the visa. There is no chance to find out later.

Comment: Thank you Traveller,  the visarefusal.com/214 b helped me although I am still not sure what  the reason for my denial is but will just have to reapply.

Answer (score 3):

A 214 B denial implies that the consular officer who was examining your visa application was not convinced that you were intending to return to your home country before the expiry of the visa. As explained [here](https://mx.usembassy.gov/visas/tourism-visitor/case-status/214-b-denials/) on the website of the US Embassy in Mexico, the consular officer has to be convinced that:

> - Has a home outside the United States that they will not abandon;
> - Is visiting the United States temporarily and will leave when the stated purpose of travel is complete;
> - Is able to pay for the trip; and
> - Meets the requirements of the visa type for which they are applying, and/or that planned activities in the U.S. are allowed by
>     that category.

The exact reason for your visa refusal is hard to tell, but will definitely be related the consular officer not being convinced about either or all of the above points mentioned.